# How do I register IEDriver and Edge Driver with Capybara while using the Webdrivers gem?

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver, capybara

The ruby webdrivers gem allows automatic downloads of drivers without me having to do it manually when my browser is updated.

And I know that latest Capybara supports drivers out of the box like `:selenium`, `:selenium_chrome`, `:selenium_chrome_headless` just to name a few. This makes it easy in that I don't have to register any drivers beforehand.

Are there similar keywords I can use for IEDriver and Edge Driver? The Webdrivers gem supports these but I am not sure how to get it working with Capybara so that the drivers are automatically downloaded and then run. If there are no keywords/default driver names I can use, how do I register these?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there are no preregistered drivers for IE or Edge. To add them you need to use `register_driver` - https://www.rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/Capybara.register_driver - and inside the block pass the options to configure selenium to use the browser you want.  You can see how Capybara registers the provided drivers by looking in https://github.com/teamcapybara/capybara/blob/master/lib/capybara/registrations/drivers.rb

Answer (score 0):

```
Capybara.register_driver :internetExplorer do |app|

    # p Capybara::Selenium::Driver::InternetExplorerDriver.options

    Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(
        app,
        :browser => :internet_explorer,
        :options =>   Selenium::WebDriver::IE::Options.new({
            :ignore_zoom_levels => true,
            :ignore_zoom_setting => true,
            # :browser_attach_timeout => 1,
            :javascript_enabled => true,
            :persistent_hover => true,
            # :require_window_focus => true,
            :ignore_protected_mode_settings =>true,
        })
    )

end

Capybara.register_driver :edgeBrowser do |app|

    # p Capybara::Selenium::Driver::InternetExplorerDriver.options

    Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(
        app,
        :browser => :edge,
        :desired_capabilities =>Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities::edge({
            :javascript_enabled => true,
            :css_selectors_enabled => true,
        }),
    )



end
```